# Pull rows between two dates when the column is in unix format

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull rows between two dates that the column is in unix format. This is the query I've come up with so far but I'm not getting any rows returned with it.

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   date_format(from_unixtime(created_time), '%Y-%m-%d') as created_date

FROM table

WHERE
   date_format(from_unixtime(created_time), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 2020-12-10 AND 2020-12-31
```

Comment: You need to put the dates in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the formatted dates in quotes.

It's better to convert the start and end times to unix times, and compare those rather than formatting all the times in the table. If the column is indexed, this will allow the index to be used. And even if it's not, it's much less work to compare numbers than format every value.

```
SELECT id, date_format(from_unixtime(created_time), '%Y-%m-%d') as created_date
FROM table
WHERE created_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-12-10') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-12-31 23:59:59')
```